# tkcalendar TclError: unknown option "-17/06/2020"

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tkcalendar

Can anyone offer some guidance please. I have a calendar widget which returns an error whenever a day in selected. The error occurs in many formats and always shows the (-) negative symbol before the date,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

root =Tk()
root.title("Calendar Selector")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Paul Hannell\python_files\Timelord.ico')

###################

#  This puts a calendar on the screen

race_day = Calendar(root, selectmode="day", date_pattern="dd/mm/yyyy")
race_day.grid(row=0, column=0)

def select_date():
    date_label.config(race_day.get_date())


calendar_button =Button(root, text="New Race Date", command=select_date)
calendar_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=20)

date_label = Label(root, text="")
date_label.grid(row=2, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce because I don't have this module installed, but it seems clear:

`date_label.config` expects an option. You are passing `'17/06/2020'` which is not recognized as a valid option: `-17/06/2020`. Hence the dash to indicate an option, not a minus-symbol ;-) I think the problem is solved when you specify the keyword name for the option as in:

```
date_label.config(text=race_day.get_date())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly it. Many, many thanks. Paul